# Upgrading software with Chocolatey using installer GUI

Tags: chocolatey

I want to upgrade a specific package (`gpg4win`) with Chocolatey, but I would like to see the actual installer and tweak some settings (specifically I want to uncheck a certain option because of [this PGP security issue](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/05/disabling-pgp-outlook-gpg4win)). How can I do that?

I've browsed through [the documentation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandsupgrade) but couldn't find ("show", "installer", "gui") anything on that page.

I've tried just running `choco upgrade gpg4win` but that just used installer defaults, showing no installer window.

For now I've resorted to manual installation to do this, but in the future I'd prefer to use chocolatey for this. Is there any flag or setting to trigger the GUI installer for chocolatey packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are after the `--not-silent` flag:

> --notsilent, --not-silent
>
> ```
> NotSilent - Do not install this silently. Defaults to false.
> ```

This is available for both the [upgrade](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-upgrade) and [install](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-install) command.

Comment: Perfect! Not sure why I didn't think of the term "silent" when searching for this feature...